# Mediapipe thread error in colab F0000 00:00:1704710377.941893 106652 threadpool_pthread_impl.cc:53] Check failed

Tags: google-colaboratory, mediapipe, worker-thread

Can someone please help me fix this issue, I am trying to use mediapipe to computer differences in facial landmarks in two different faces. The code works at first but after several steps it breaks and I am getting this error

```
type here
WARNING: All log messages before absl::InitializeLog() is called are written to STDERR
F0000 00:00:1704710377.941893  106652 threadpool_pthread_impl.cc:53] Check failed: res == 0 (11 vs. 0) pthread_create failed
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @     0x7d6b03b093e9  absl::lts_20230125::log_internal::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
    @     0x7d6b02ddd170  mediapipe::ThreadPool::WorkerThread::WorkerThread()
    @     0x7d6b035c79e0  mediapipe::ThreadPool::StartWorkers()
    @     0x7d6b035aa0b0  mediapipe::ThreadPoolExecutor::Start()
    @     0x7d6b035aa232  mediapipe::ThreadPoolExecutor::ThreadPoolExecutor()
    @     0x7d6b035aa407  mediapipe::ThreadPoolExecutor::Create()
    @     0x7d6b03594450  mediapipe::CalculatorGraph::CreateDefaultThreadPool()
    @     0x7d6b03594672  mediapipe::CalculatorGraph::InitializeDefaultExecutor()
    @     0x7d6b03595055  mediapipe::CalculatorGraph::InitializeExecutors()
    @     0x7d6b03595c28  mediapipe::CalculatorGraph::Initialize()
    @     0x7d6b03596314  mediapipe::CalculatorGraph::Initialize()
    @     0x7d6b0359650f  mediapipe::CalculatorGraph::Initialize()
    @     0x7d6b0351295d  mediapipe::python::CalculatorGraphSubmodule()::{lambda()#1}::operator()()
    @     0x7d6b03512cf9  pybind11::cpp_function::initialize<>()::{lambda()#3}::_FUN()
    @     0x7d6b02e2a992  pybind11::cpp_function::dispatcher()
    @     0x560389a37093  PyCFunction_Call


 
from torch import nn
import mediapipe as mp
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

class MouthLandmarkLoss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MouthLandmarkLoss, self).__init__()
        self.mp_face_mesh = mp.solutions.face_mesh.FaceMesh(static_image_mode=True,
                                                            max_num_faces=1,
                                                            refine_landmarks=True,
                                                            min_detection_confidence=0.5)

    def extract_landmarks(self, images):
        landmarks_list = []
        specific_landmark_indices = [61, 146, 146, 91, 91, 181, 181, 84, 84, 17, 17, 314, 314, 405, 405, 321,
                                      321, 375, 375, 291, 61, 185, 185, 40, 40, 39, 39, 37, 37, 0, 0, 267, 267,
                                      269, 269, 270, 270, 409, 409, 291, 78, 95, 95, 88, 88, 178, 178, 87, 87, 14,
                                      14, 317, 317, 402, 402, 318, 318, 324, 324, 308, 78, 191, 191, 80, 80, 81,
                                      81, 82, 82, 13, 13, 312, 312, 311, 311, 310, 310, 415, 415, 308]
        for image in images:
            dense_img = image.to_dense()
            img = dense_img.detach().permute(1, 2, 0).cpu().numpy()
            img_save = (img * 127.5 + 128).clip(0, 255).astype(np.uint8)

            # Convert to BGR if the image has 3 channels
            if img_save.shape[2] == 3:
                img_save = cv2.cvtColor(img_save, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

            face_detection = mp.solutions.face_detection.FaceDetection(min_detection_confidence=0.3)
            face_detection_results = face_detection.process(img_save)

            # Check if face is detected
            if face_detection_results.detections:
                bounding_box = face_detection_results.detections[0].location_data.relative_bounding_box

                # Process the image with Mediapipe Face Mesh
                face_mesh_results = self.mp_face_mesh.process(img_save)

                # Extract only mouth landmarks
                if face_mesh_results.multi_face_landmarks:
                    mouth_landmarks = face_mesh_results.multi_face_landmarks[0]

                    # Extract specific landmarks using the defined indices
                    specific_landmarks = torch.tensor([[mouth_landmarks.landmark[i].x, mouth_landmarks.landmark[i].y] for i in specific_landmark_indices], dtype=torch.float32)
            
                    # Draw smaller circles for landmarks
                    for landmark in specific_landmarks:
                        x, y = int(landmark[0] * img_save.shape[1]), int(landmark[1] * img_save.shape[0])
                        cv2.circle(img_save, (x, y), 1, (0, 255, 0), -1)

                    # Display the image with smaller circles
                    h, w, _ = img_save.shape
                    x, y, width, height = int(bounding_box.xmin * w), int(bounding_box.ymin * h), int(bounding_box.width * w), int(bounding_box.height * h)
                    cv2.rectangle(img_save, (x, y), (x + width, y + height), (0, 255, 0), 2)

                    # Append the mouth landmarks to the list
                    landmarks_list.append(specific_landmarks)
        # Save the image with drawn smaller circles (only for debugging)
        # cv2.imwrite('/content/img.png', img_save)
        if landmarks_list:
           return torch.stack(landmarks_list)
        else:
          # Handle the case when all tensors are empty
           return torch.empty(0)

    def calculate_distances(self, landmarks):
        # Calculate pairwise Euclidean distances between landmarks
        num_landmarks = landmarks.shape[1]
        distances = torch.norm(landmarks.unsqueeze(1) - landmarks.unsqueeze(0), dim=-1)
        return distances.view(-1, num_landmarks * num_landmarks)

    def forward(self, y_hat, y):
        # Assuming x and y_hat are batches of images in tensor format
        # x and y_hat shape: (batch_size, channels, height, width)
        # Extract landmarks using MediaPipe Face Mesh for the mouth
        landmarks_y = self.extract_landmarks(y)
        landmarks_y_hat = self.extract_landmarks(y_hat)

        # Create masks indicating the presence of landmarks
        landmarks_mask_y = torch.any(landmarks_y != 0, dim=-1)
        landmarks_mask_y_hat = torch.any(landmarks_y_hat != 0, dim=-1)

        # Ensure that both landmarks_y and landmarks_y_hat have at least one landmark
        if not torch.any(landmarks_mask_y) or not torch.any(landmarks_mask_y_hat):
            # No landmarks detected, return zero loss
            return torch.tensor(0.000000001, dtype=torch.float32, device=y.device)

        # Apply the masks to landmarks_y and landmarks_y_hat
        landmarks_y_masked = landmarks_y[landmarks_mask_y]
        landmarks_y_hat_masked = landmarks_y_hat[landmarks_mask_y_hat]

        # Calculate distances between landmarks
        distances_y = self.calculate_distances(landmarks_y_masked)
        distances_y_hat = self.calculate_distances(landmarks_y_hat_masked)

        # Round off distances to two decimal places
        distances_y = torch.round(distances_y * 100) / 100
        distances_y_hat = torch.round(distances_y_hat * 100) / 100
        # Calculate expression loss based on rounded distances
        loss = F.mse_loss(distances_y_hat, distances_y)
        # Add a regularizer term to the loss
        
        regularizer = 1000
        loss *= regularizer
        
        return loss
```

I tried to calculate landmark loss for in two different images and it is supposed to return a loss calculated through code using mediapipe
i am using google colab pro+'s Tesla V100 gpu? here is the code